# How Do I Change the Dialect in Dapper Extensions?

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

By default, the RDBMS dialect for dapper extensions is SqlServer. How do I change this to another dialect?

I've figured I can do: (I'm just quickly throwing together a pgsql dialect)

`var conf = new DapperExtensionsConfiguration(typeof(AutoClassMapper<>), new List<Assembly>(), new DapperExtensions.Sql.PostgreSqlDialect());`

but what do I do with this conf? Do I set it to the connection or to a static method somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Figured it out! DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new PostgreSqlDialect();

Answer (score 19):

The solution is:

```
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new PostgreSqlDialect();
```

Please note that the dialect must be manually set for asynchronous extensions as well:

```
DapperExtensions.DapperAsyncExtensions.SqlDialect = new PostgreSqlDialect();
```

Comment: (Posting as community wiki since I'm just copying the OP's comment into an answer)